# mpiexec command running a neural network on Python but not printing

Tags: python, windows, deep-learning, neural-network, mpi

So I want to run a neural network using the mpiexec command.

When I use the mpiexec -n 12 python C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Desktop\Internship\new_es\example_es.py, the code runs (according to task manager, it is running the processes), but it does not print anything, for example, the training progress. After running the command, it stays as in the screenshot.

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMdT7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMdT7.png)

When I run just python C:\Users\Usuario\OneDrive\Desktop\Internship\new_es\example_es.py, it prints fine.

This is the code that it is running:

`def train_es():
last_t = time.time()
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)

```
        ###
        def eval_fn(model):
            output = network(data)
            loss = F.nll_loss(output, target).cpu().item()
            return loss
        loss = optimizer.step(eval_fn) 
        ###

        if batch_idx % log_interval == 0  and  optimizer.is_master:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
              epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
              100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))
            print('\t time: ', time.time()-last_t)
            last_t = time.time()

    if optimizer.is_master:
        print('EVAL at the end of each epoch: ')
        test()  ## Baseline: 98.43%

#torch.save(network.state_dict(), 'model.pth')
#torch.save(optimizer.state_dict(), 'optimizer.pth')
```

train_es()
`

What can I do for it to print the progress, as it should do?

Windows 11, Python.